# Convert Dataframe to xts: Issue with Daylight Savings and NAs

Tags: r, plot, xts, quantmod

I'm struggling with some basic xts functionality. I'm reading a CSV data file and trying to plot the data with the `candleChart()` function (from the quantmod package). I'm experiencing some issues after transforming my data.frame to an xts object due to daylight saving time.

Basically, the data are OHLC from EUR/USD currency pair in a one minute - timeframe. This year daylight saving time was implemented on the 27th of March 2016 between 02:00 and 03:00am. After converting the data.frame to xts, the 60 indexes in that time window are missing (`NA`).

Below you'll find a the code. I attached the [data file](https://github.com/cybercedric/Testrepo/blob/master/EURUSD_UTC_1%20Min_Bid_2016.01.02_2016.10.15_cleaned.csv) too. Is there any easy way to fix the convert the data without losing anything?

```
forexData <- read.csv(fileName, sep = ".", dec = ",")
#View(forexData)

dataSerie <- xts(forexData[,2:6], order.by=as.POSIXct(forexData[,1], tz=""))

# Checking if data index contains "NA"s and save index where NA are located
index_NA <- which(is.na(index(dataSerie)))

if(length(index_NA) == 0) {
  candleChart(dataSerie, name="First Plot", subset="last 3 weeks", bar.type="ohlc")

} else {
  print("!!! Warning !!! - Data index contains NAs")
}
```

Comment: It looks like your decimals are formatted with a comma (`,`); so add `dec = ","` to your `read.csv` call: `forexData <- read.csv(fileName, sep = ".", dec=",")`. That may not be your only problem, but it sure is a good start.

Comment: Thx a lot Abdou, It actually was the problem, .. I figured it ou and set the dec to "," everythings went fine... but I'm stucked at the next problem:

Comment: Please add the error from the next problem to your question, so that somebody may be able to help.

Comment: I read the data from csv and transformed to a xts() object, and get a lot of NAs aftre transformation. Data seems to be fine.. the code is below .. `forexData <- read.csv(fileName, sep = ".", dec = ",")

dataSerie <- xts(forexData[,2:6], order.by=as.POSIXct(forexData[, 1], tz="", format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))

candleChart(dataSerie, name="First Plot", subset="last 3 weeks", bar.type = "ohlc")`

Comment: When trying plotting the data I receive following error: _Error in periodicity(x) : can not calculate periodicity of 1 observation_  I guess because of the NAs

Comment: Can you please add those comments to the question itself? Not just comments.

Comment: ok - I'll update my question

Answer (score 0):

The header of your CSV is:

```
TimeUTC.Open.High.Low.Close.Volume
```

So the timestamp column appears to be in UTC, which does not have daylight saving time. So you should specify the timezone as UTC in your call to `as.POSIXct`:

```
dataSerie <- xts(forexData[,2:6], order.by=as.POSIXct(forexData[,1], tz="UTC"))
```